# validate size of upload using Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

In our latest application we need to process some uploads, I've worked with paperclip before and everything just works! but we're giving [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) a try, it looks promising but, I can't find **how to validate the size of an attachment**, it seems like the [documentation](http://carrierwave.rubyforge.org/rdoc/) doesn't have any information about it, should we add it manually to the model via a custom validator?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems like they don't have it (yet) Just added this custom validator to my model, => https://gist.github.com/795665

Comment: i was working with the above solution a bit myself.  just be aware that that will only validate the size of the image after it has been stored in the cache.  in terms of client side validation i still am looking myself

Comment: If you want to secure your site from uploading ridiculously large files, CarrierWave validations won't help, instead learn [how to secure server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200188/rails-file-upload-size-limit). CarrierWave file size validations could be useful if you want to have different size limits for videos and images or you want to validate minimum file size.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a Wiki entry on github: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Validate-attachment-file-size

Comment: This verifies after file is uploaded, which can be a problem for those using Amazon S3.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for some way to validate before file is uploaded.

Comment: If u need verification before upload, you can use [file validators](https://github.com/musaffa/file_validators) gem.

Answer (score 5):

I've made an Active Model [File Validators](https://github.com/musaffa/file_validators) gem that checks content type and file size validation for Carrierwave, PaperClip, Drangonfly, Refile (hopefully it will work with other uploading solutions). It detects the content type based on the content of the file and it has a media type spoof detector. It works both before and after uploads.

Answer (score 5):

Since `1.0` version CarrierWave has built-in file size validation.

Install latest `carrierwave` gem

```
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
```

Add method `size_range` to provide a min size and a max size

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def size_range
    0..2.megabytes
  end
```

In model add `validates_integrity_of` to valid a file size (and content type) of an image.

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates_integrity_of :image
```

Answer (score -1):

[Here is the solution](https://gist.github.com/peter/9408229) that I came up with - the trick was that I couldn't check the file size directly as that made the Fog RubyGem bomb if the file hadn't been uploaded. I would expect there to be a cleaner way to ask CarrierWave if a file was uploaded.