# Change upload file size limit with Ruby Passanger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload

I am currently running in house software  built on ruby on rails. We use passenger.
We currently have a file size limit of 15MB for uploading files to the rail application. How can I increase this file size limitation? I am not at all familiar  with ruby and don't even know where to start looking. 
I tried editing the apache configuration by adding the LimitRequestBody line in the virtual host, but no cigar.

Comment: Hiya, this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200188/rails-file-upload-size-limit **or** this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody cheers,

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem; he stated explicitly that he tried that. I'm pretty sure Apache doesn't have an upload limit. Not sure what else would be causing that.

Comment: I have the same issue and no idea what causing that, please let me know if you solve that.