# Max size to upload files in the Dreamhost Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dreamhost

How can I set max size to upload files in the Dreamhost Passenger?

Comment: What kind of upload library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to do this directly in Passenger, but the limit is based on the apache request body limit. So, you would need to edit your httpd.conf file and use LimitRequestBody to set it (meaning you'd also need a VPS or dedicated server with us). Please see the top answer here with the solution for Apache:

[Rails file upload size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200188/rails-file-upload-size-limit)